# Partial Derivatives of a continuous function is the Dirac distribution

Tags: distribution-theory

I am having trouble with the following question and a detailed solution would be immensely appreciated:

Determine a continuous function $f:\to \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{F}$ and a multi-index $ \alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$ such that $\partial^{\alpha}f = \delta_0$

Comment: If $\nabla f=\delta_0$, then a primitive of $f$ would be in order.

Comment: For $n=1$ try $f(x) = {1 \over 2}(x+|x|)$ and $\alpha = 2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \prod_k x_k 1_{[0,\infty)}(x_k)$ and define the distribution
$T(\phi) = \int f(x) \phi(x) dx$.

Note that $\partial^{(2,...,2)} T(\phi) = \int f(x) \partial^{(2,...,2)} \phi(x) dx = \phi(0)$.